# Declaration or statement expected on export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why am I able to do this:

```
export const state = {};
```

but I can't do this:

```
const state = {}
export state; // 'Declaration or statement expected' error
```

Comment: Try export {state};

Comment: @Lalit thanks! But, why exactly should I do it that way?

Comment: Because of its syntax. You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Well @Lalit, that's over simplifying it, the reason would be that this gets changed to `export { state: state }` where one can then `import { state } from 'foo'` afterwards

Answer (score 10):

So you have 2ways to use export:
This one you've already done:

```
export const state = /*whatever you want*/
```

And this one:

```
const state = /*whatever you want*/
export { state };
```

And then you may use it with:

```
import { state } from './otherFileName'
```

Quote from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> export { name1, name2, …, nameN };
> export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };
> export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // also var, function
> export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const
> ```

Comment: I've tried those